# Json encode return nothing for certain column

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have 1700 rows in my table. Problem is I can't get the json output if i try to use **des** column, no output is showing in the browser. If i try to get other columns except des, output is showing. Then i tried with limit key word and i limited to 1240 , then gave me an output even with the des column. But I need all the records with des column. I have put my php scripts in XAMPP server.

**This is my php.**

```
<?php

 require_once 'include/Configg_t.php';
 //header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE,$con) or die("db selection failed");


    $r=mysql_query("SELECT * from tbl_mas_material LIMIT 1240");

    $result = array();

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)){
        array_push($result,
        array('des'=>$row[1]));}

        echo json_encode(array("feed" => $result));
       json_last_error();
    mysql_close($con); 



?>
```

problem is occur with the des column in the table.

this is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_mas_material` (
  `material` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  `des` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `matgrp` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`material`,`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If I add **des** to my query no output is showing.

Comment: My hipotehesis failed. Deleted my answer and will think about it. If I got any idea I'll re-answer it.

Comment: ok, thank you very much

Comment: if i use print_r() rather than echo json_encode it show me the whole result. I think problem with the echo json_encode

Comment: is your data confidential? can you export it to a file and put it on pastebin or upload it to http://sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: yes sir it is confidential.. :(
i have address the matter differently here . can you check it plz?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860024/json-output-error-no-output-with-getting-data-from-the-server-using-php

Comment: ok , i will give you part of data. Because this has also the same problem. i can't take a json output if i try to get **des**... **SELECT des from tbl_test_mas_material** not working. this is the creation table 

CREATE TABLE `tbl_test_mas_material` (
  `material` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  `des` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`material`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
 how do i upload the CSV file to sqlfiddle.com?

Answer (score 0):

```
 array_push($result, array('des'=>$row[1]));}
```

Can you please check, des value refers to the $row[1]?

Try changing it to

```
 array_push($result, array('des' => $row['des']));
```

Comment: still nothing happen. if i limit it to 1240. it worked as earlier

Comment: if i use print_r() rather than echo json_encode it show me the whole result. I think problem with the echo json_encode